# How to wait for onLocationChanged() in LocationListener in the same place that invoked requestLocationUpdates()?

Tags: android, asynchronous, wakelock, locationlistener, commonsware-cwac

I'm writing a GPS tracking app. I'm using CommonsWare WakefulIntentService and AlarmReceiver to schedule fixing locations from GPS. The problem is that I must use doWakefulWork() method is meant to be used with synchronous blocking processes where what I have is an asynchronous non-blocking method. So how should I fix GPS locations using onLocationChanged() in LocationListener and requestLocationUpdates() from doWakefulWork() method?

Solved:

I just found out that this functionality already has been implemented in [LocationPoller](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using CommonsWare WakefulIntentService and AlarmReceiver to schedule fixing locations from GPS.

That will not work well.

> So how should I fix GPS locations using onLocationChanged() in LocationListener and requestLocationUpdates() from doWakefulWork() method?

Ideally, you wouldn't. `IntentService` is designed for making synchronous stuff (e.g., Web transactions, database transactions) synchronous. It is not designed for making asynchronous stuff even more asynchronous (a-asynchronous?)..

> I just found out that this functionality already has been implemented in [LocationPoller](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll).

Whether you use `LocationPoller`, the fork, or something derived from it, using a `Service` for intrinsically asynchronous work is a better plan.